# Animating adding a table row (JavaScript + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I've written some code to add a table row which you can see below.

```
function addRow(pos) {

// Insert new HTML table row
var tblObj = document.getElementById('questionTbl');
var newRow = tblObj.insertRow(pos + 1);  

// Add new table cells
var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
newCell1.innerHTML = 'one';

var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
newCell2.innerHTML = 'two';

var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
newCell3.innerHTML = 'three';

var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
newCell4.innerHTML = 'four';

var newCell5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
newCell5.innerHTML = 'five';

var newCell6 = newRow.insertCell(5);
newCell6.innerHTML = 'six';

var newCell7 = newRow.insertCell(6);
newCell7.innerHTML = 'seven';
```

I have since added the jQuery library as I wanted some functionality that I haven't forseen (otherwise I would've done the Add Row stuff in query).

```
newRow.id = "row_" + (pos + 1);
newRow.className = "hide";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#row_" + (pos + 1)).switchClass("hide", "show-row");
});
```

The adding of the row works, but it doesn't animate. There is a delay in it appearing (which I guess would be the time it takes to animate).

Does anyone know why the animation isn't working?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#row_" + (pos + 1)).removeClass("hide").addClass("show-row").hide().show('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addRow(pos) {

    // Insert new HTML table row
    var tblObj = document.getElementById('questionTbl');
    var newRow = tblObj.insertRow(pos + 1);  

    // Add new table cells
    var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    newCell1.innerHTML = 'one';

    var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    newCell2.innerHTML = 'two';

    var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    newCell3.innerHTML = 'three';

    var newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    newCell4.innerHTML = 'four';

    var newCell5 = newRow.insertCell(4);
    newCell5.innerHTML = 'five';

    var newCell6 = newRow.insertCell(5);
    newCell6.innerHTML = 'six';

    var newCell7 = newRow.insertCell(6);
    newCell7.innerHTML = 'seven';

    newRow.id = "row_" + (pos + 1);
    newRow.className = "hide";

    $("#row_" + (pos + 1)).switchClass("hide", "show-row");
}
```

[`$(document).ready(function() { ... }`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) should be used when you need code executed as soon as the DOM is ready to be manipulated, basically the function passed to the `ready` function is executed on page load. The original jQuery code would never execute as the function was attached to the [ready *event*](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) after the ready event had already been fired.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't use the $(document).ready(function() { initially, but put it in there when I was running out of ideas!